# How to create an Amazon EC2 HVM Ubuntu AMI?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, amazon-ami

It's surprisingly hard to find straightforward information on how to create an EC2 HVM AMI.

My goal is to create an HVM AMI that boots from an ***ext2*** root volume into Ubuntu.

That's all, nothing more.  But there seems to be almost no information anywhere giving straight down the line instructions for how to do so, despite extensive Googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I build ami image with packer

https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon.html